# Algorithm creating polygon of n corners inside a square (HTML5 - Canvas)?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, canvas, polygon

Consider the following setup :

CSS :

```css
div {
    position :absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

HTML :

```
<div id="container">
    <canvas id="my-canvas"/>
</div>
```

Now inside `#my-canvas` I want to be able to draw a polygon with any number of corners that always sits on one of its sides (and not one of its corners). The height and width that the polygon will "take up" should always be equal to that of its parent (in this case 200px X 200px) which we will assume that it's always going to be a square.

Is there a standard algorithm to achieve that (without using any JS libraries)?

Drawing a polygon with 4 corners inside `#my-container` is the easiest I guess as you will basically be creating a square of equal size :

```
var c = document.getElementById('my-canvas').getContext('2d');
var side = document.getElementById('container').clientHeight;
c.fillStyle = '#f00';
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(0, 0);
c.lineTo(0, side);
c.lineTo(side, side);
c.lineTo(side, 0);
c.closePath();
c.fill();
```

But what about a polygon with 5 corners or n corners ?

```
var corners = 5;
var c = document.getElementById('my-canvas').getContext('2d');
var side = (document.getElementById('container').clientHeight * 4) / corners;
c.fillStyle = '#f00';
c.beginPath();
c.moveTo(0, 0);
// ok the following is totally wrong, but I'm sure there is a loop involved and that the x & y
// should increment/decrement each time around in some way, relevant to the value of *side*
for (var i=0; i<corners; i++) {
   c.lineTo((side*i), side);
} 
c.closePath();
c.fill();
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

**NOTE :**

I am only interested in polygons whose sides are of equal length (I guess this is what you'd call a "regular" polygon?).

Since we're in the HTML/CSS universe, the smallest side allowed will obviously be that of a length of 1px. So this is the only restriction.

The type of polygons I'm referring to are the ones found at the bottom left of [this image](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Polygon_types.svg/750px-Polygon_types.svg.png). Apparently they are of type "regular convex" ? Apologies but I'm not a mathematician.

Comment: Inscribed lines: `P1=[sin(a*n)*r+Cx, cos(a*n)*r+Cy]; P2=[sin(a*(n+1))*r+Cx, cos(a*(n+1))*r+Cy]; n=0..Nc`.

Comment: I did this in Java (as a polygon). Basically, you start from the center of your rectangle, and use the x / y radii to go around in a circle in n-vertex steps, which each angle increasing by 2 * PI / # vertexes. If you want to see the code let me know

Comment: Interesting equation but I don't know what `P1`,`P2`,`a`, `r`, `Cx`, `Cy` represent. I'm guessing `n` is the number of corners ?

Comment: Thanks ControlAltDel. Yeah I'd love t see the code but it's best that you post it as a generic algorithm so that I can think of its JS version. :-)

Comment: `P`s are start and end points of a single side in a polygon. `Nc` is the total amount of corners, `a` is the starting angle of the first side related to X-axis, `r` is the radius of a virtual circle, wherein you'll draw the polygon and `C`s are the coordinates of the centre point of that circle.

Comment: @Teemu - That would be the solution for the largest regular polygon inscribed in a circle. For inscribing in a square, I assume you mean that the radius should be half the side length of the square. However, I believe that the largest inscribed regular polygon will be slightly larger when the number of sides is odd. The problem then reduces to determining the radius to use.

Comment: @TedHopp You're right, but it's not hard to calculate the largest circle in a square, that's needed when initializing `r`.

Comment: @Teemu - That will give too small a polygon when the number of sides is odd. It's easy to see when you try it with a triangle.

Comment: @TedHopp I can't see any connection to the count of corners in my "equation", it should work starting from `Nc=3`, when the first side starts at `[r, 0]`. Probably it needs some adjusting to get the polygon always to "sit"  on a side though.

Comment: note that your requirement of "always having an edge on a side" cannot be fulfilled. Even something as simple as a hexagon cannot have two of its neighbouring vertices on an edge of your rectangle AND fit in the rectangle: if we label them p1,...,p6, then p1 and p2, as well as p4 and p5, will lie on an edge of your bounding rectangle, but p3 and p6 will then be outside that rectangle. There are square-inscribing algorithms, but that extra requirement creates a geometrically impossible constraint =)

Comment: @Teemu - If you inscribe a circle in the square and then a triangle in the circle, the triangle will be smaller than the largest triangle that will fit in the square with one triangle side sitting on a side of the square.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - I assumed that OP simply means for the polygon to be as large as possible within the square under the constraint that one side of the polygon lies on a side of the square.

Comment: the fact that OP was pretty explicit about that constraint at least warranted the note. Hopefully they didn't realise that extra bit would lead to an impossible geometry and they've just learned something =)

Comment: Sprout Coder - I've been assuming that your intention is to have a regular polygon. But you don't actually say as much, so is that correct?

Comment: @Teemu - No it is not. Please try with a pencil and paper. A regular triangle with side length equal to the square will fit inside the square with one side coincident with a side of the square, but it will not fit inside a circle inscribed in the square.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans - A polygon has distinct sides by definition so it can always sit on one of them and not one one of its corners. Also the polygon I'm referring to should have sides of equal length. So a hexagon can obviously sit on whichever one of its six sides of equal length.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion in regards to the "type" of polygons I'm referring to. Please see the "NOTE" section in my OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple..

- divide a circle into x amount of sides, 360 / x = angle of side
- calculate each point of shape
- calculate the angle of a face
- rotate shape so face is flat into the container
- re-scale points to fit boundaries

any doubts.. just check the code below

```js
//load data
var c = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
var width = document.getElementById('canvas').clientWidth;
var height = document.getElementById('canvas').clientHeight;
var corners = 5;
//initial calculation
var radius = 1;
var angle = (Math.PI * 2) / corners;

//build points 
var points = [];
for (var i=0; i<corners; i++)
{
    var a = angle * i;
    //sin and cos are swithced,point 0 is bottom one
    var x = (Math.sin(a)*radius);
    var y = (Math.cos(a)*radius);
    points.push({
        x:x
        ,y:y
    })
} 
//get the angle of a side
var sideangle = Math.atan2(points[1].y-points[0].y, points[1].x-points[0].x)
//rotate point around bottom one
var o = points[0];
for (var i=1; i<points.length; i++)
{
    points[i] = {
        x:Math.cos(sideangle) * (points[i].x - o.x) - Math.sin(sideangle) * (points[i].y-o.y) + o.x
        ,y:Math.sin(sideangle) * (points[i].x - o.x) + Math.cos(sideangle) * (points[i].y - o.y) + o.y
    };
}
//by this point the figure is "flat on the floor" lets measure its size
var rect = {top:2,left:2,right:-2,bottom:-2};
for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++)
{
    rect.top = Math.min(rect.top,points[i].y);
    rect.bottom = Math.max(rect.bottom,points[i].y);
    rect.left = Math.min(rect.left,points[i].x);
    rect.right = Math.max(rect.right,points[i].x);
}
rect.width = Math.abs(rect.right - rect.left);
rect.height = Math.abs(rect.bottom - rect.top);
//make points relative to top left of rect
for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++)
{
    points[i] = {
        x: points[i].x - rect.left
        ,y: points[i].y - rect.top
    };
}
//lets scale and position the poly based on its rect
var ratioX = width / rect.width
var ratioY = height / rect.height
var ratio = Math.min(ratioX, ratioY);

for (var i=0; i<points.length; i++)
{
    points[i] = {
        x: (points[i].x * ratio)
        ,y: (points[i].y * ratio)
    };
}

//draw path
c.beginPath();

c.moveTo(points[0].x, points[0].y);
for (var i=1; i<points.length; i++)
    c.lineTo(points[i].x, points[i].y);
c.closePath();
//draw
c.strokeStyle='#f00'
c.stroke();
c.fillStyle = '#f00';
//c.fill();
```

```css
canvas{
    position :absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
```

```html
<!--size must be defined as attribute-->
<canvas width='300' height='200' id="canvas"/>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is actually a not a simple problem. First, let's state the problem less ambiguously:

> Given a square of side length *S* and an integer *n* ≥ 3, determine the maximum length *L* such that a regular, convex polygon with *n* sides of length *L* can be constructed so that:
>
> 1. one side of the polygon lies on a side of the square;
> 2. the polygon is contained within the square.

Note that this does *not* require that the polygon touch the square anywhere other than on the side that lies on a side of the square. (Although for *n* > 3, it's not too hard to show that there will be other points of contact.)

Once one has the side length *L*, it's fairly easy to then construct the polygon itself. Let's do that first (because it will help with the first part). From simple trig, the center of the polygon will be a distance

> *h* = *L* / (2 ⋅ tan(π / *n*))

above the center of the polygon's bottom side, which (from symmetry) will also be the center of the bottom side of the square. For the rest of this, let's assume that the center of the polygon is the origin of our coordinate system, with the +X axis to the right and the +Y axis up. (Note that our Y axis is reversed from the usual computer graphics coordinate system.) The radius of the polygon (the distance from the center to each vertex) will be

> *r* = *L* / (2 ⋅ sin(π / *n*))

Let's call the above **Equation 1**; we will refer back to it at the end. The vertices will be given by:

> *x<sub>i</sub>* = *r* ⋅ cos(*θ*<sub>0</sub> + 2 ⋅ π ⋅ *i* / *n*)
>   *y<sub>i</sub>* = *r* ⋅ sin(*θ*<sub>0</sub> + 2 ⋅ π ⋅ *i* / *n*)

where *θ*<sub>0</sub> is a "phase angle" that determines the rotation of the polygon. We want the rotation to be such that the bottom side of the polygon is horizontal. If we want the first vertex (*i* = 0) to be the right vertex of the polygon's bottom, then we should use

> *θ*<sub>0</sub> = −π / 2

With that substitution, our coordinate equations simplify to:

> *x<sub>i</sub>* = *r* ⋅ sin(2 ⋅ π ⋅ *i* / *n*)
>   *y<sub>i</sub>* = −*r* ⋅ cos(2 ⋅ π ⋅ *i* / *n*)

For future reference, the above will be **Equation 2**. Now we need to determine *L*. It's easier, I think, to invert the problem: for a given *L*, what is the smallest *S* such that a square of side length *S* can contain the polygon with one side containing a side of the polygon. We can then scale everything to match the given square of the original problem. But this is pretty easy. Let's use *L* = 1. For *n* even, the diameter *d* of the polygon (the largest distance between points on the polygon) is

> *d* = 2 ⋅ *r* = 1 / sin(π / *n*)      (*n* even)

For *n* odd, it's not too hard to see that the diameter is the distance from one vertex on the base to the vertex at the top of the polygon. With a little construction (left to the reader) and the law of cosines, that turns out to be:

> *d* = sqrt([1 + cos(π / *n*)] / [2 ⋅ sin<sup>2</sup>(π / *n*)])      (*n* odd)

In both cases, it's easy to establish that at least one diameter of the polygon is horizontal. Thus, the side of the smallest square that contains the polygon (with the polygon base resting on the bottom of the square) must be at least the diameter, and (by definition of the diameter of the polygon) the square never has to be larger.

Since we want to scale everything so that the side of the square measures the given quantity *S*, we finally have:

> *L* = *S* / *d*

So the algorithm to construct the polygon is to first determine *L* as we've just described, then use Equation 1 to compute *r*, and finally use Equation 2 to compute the vertices, which should be connected sequentially to form the polygon.